# Need help with simple turnaround render

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging

[image]

This is my first time using blender so bear with me please. When trying to render a turnaround gif I keep running into problems- so far:

1. The keyframes auto changing to match each other. If frame 1 is 0 rotation, and I change frame 36 to 355 rotation, frame 1 will become 355 as well.
2. My rig isnt turning with my mesh, despite being parented. this leads to the arms freaking out like so

[image]

3. The platform + tools rotate on a very different axis than the character model mesh does.

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated, youtube and google have been no help with these :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turnarounds are generally made leaving the character still, and having the camera orbiting: this can be achieved creating an empty in the center of the orbit, parenting the camera to the empty and rotating the empty: you will have to set at frame 1 a rot keyframe value of 0, then set at frame 37 a Z rotation of 360 (Euler rotation), then go to graph editor, select all keyframes, press T and set the interpolation to "linear" and run the animation from 1 to 36.

If you really want to rotate the character, as it is posed, every movement has to be performed by the armature in pose mode, do not rotate the mesh in object mode, because the character is child of the armature, not the inverse. If it is not present, you will have to create a "Main" bone and set all others bones child of the main, eventually parenting all tools and platform to it, then animate the rotation of the main bone.

Comment: thank you so much! that worked perfectly :)